# Update a rich text column in Sharepoint using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am trying to update a column(type - Multiple Lines of Text/Rich Text) using jquery and I am unable to do so .

Below is the code that I am using to achieve that .

```
function getmkemod(mke, md) {

   var category = "Event";
   //CAML Query Here
   var retval = new Array(), i=0;
   //var retval = "";
   $().SPServices({
       operation: "GetListItems",
       listName: "Products",
       async: false,
       CAMLQuery: x,
       completefunc: function(xData, ID) {

           $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=z:row]").each(function() {
               retval[i++] = $(this).attr("ows_ProdIDMenu");

           });
       }
   });
$("#ctl00_m_g_8bdaafbb_e52a_43db_a50c_a96544b1eab2_ctl00_ctl04_ctl55_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").val("Hi");


         // alert(t);
  // t.innerText = "<div>Hi</div>";
}
```

I am unable to update the t value as Hi. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I got it. I thought it might help someone.

$("textarea[Title='Test']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']").contents().find("body").html("hi");

Answer (score 1):

I might add to the @Janet answer that it works for Rich text multiline columns.
For Enhanced rich text columns I may add that code:

```
$('td.ms-formbody').each(function(i, item) {
    item = $(item);
    if (item.html().indexOf('FieldName="' + fieldName + '"') > -1) {
        item.find("div[contenteditable='true']").html(newValue);
        //break
        return false;
    }
});
```