# Set default value for Sharepoint 2010 Enhanced rich text box

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to set default value to "enhanced rich text box" of a list in sharepoint 2010. 
A similar question is being answered here [Update a rich text column in Sharepoint using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334225/update-a-rich-text-column-in-sharepoint-using-jquery)

Found this code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13158954/1826736)

```
$('td.ms-formbody').each(function(i, item) {
item = $(item);
if (item.html().indexOf('FieldName="' + fieldName + '"') > -1) {
    item.find("div[contenteditable='true']").html(newValue);
    //break
    return false;
}
});
```

The above piece of code smartly does the job in 2010 environment but somehow the default value appears and then disappears in a fraction of second. My guess is that as soon as "editing tools" appear for enhanced rich text box control, they wipe out its default content. I am executing this code from within Document.ready. Please help me fix the issue. A similar code works fine in sharepoint 2007 but not sure why Sharepoint 2010 is behaving like this.

Comment: No takers? Someone help please...

Comment: how did your js code is injected in the page, can you try to defer it after sharepoint js code loaded?